# How to load/unload Word Add-in programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I'd like to know how I can programatically load and unload a VSTO add-in in Word. I'm using Word 2007 and VS2010 with C#.

I thought I might have some luck with using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.COMAddins and .Addins properties, but the .Addins property gives an empty list and COMAddins is a collection of opaque COM objects.

An [alternative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817452/comaddins-how-to-turn-them-on-off-programmatically-in-office-word-2003) suggests making the ribbon menu invisible, but I actually want to unload the add-in altogether.

Comment: I'd be *very* surprised if you find a way of doing it in C# code - being able to do so requires isolation of each plugin into separate AppDomain which I don't think is there for Office plugins (you can check yourself by enumerating all AppDomains).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar requirement and achieved it by little cheat.

I had a addin called AddinLauncher (with no ribbons) which will look for the user type and launch or closes the other addin.

This code was called during AddinLauncher Addin Startup event.

```
foreach (COMAddIn addin in Globals.ThisAddin.Application.COMAddins)
{
  if (**specify your own condition**)
    {
        addin.Connect = true;
    }                       
}
```

The following changes are required in your deployment

The Loadbehaviour for AddinLaucher addin is 3 and all the other addins are 0.
More about Loadbehaviour [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386106.aspx)

Comment: Hello, I have found out that you can even perform a "reload" of your Add-In: 
`
public void ReloadVstoAddIn() { var addIn = Application.COMAddIns.Item("<ADDIN_PROG_ID>"); addIn.Connect = false; //Unloads the Add-In addIn.Connect = true; //Triggers AddInBase.Startup event again } 
`
Regards, Jörg

Comment: Sorry, that does only seem to work in the debugger. When I have tested my installed solution, my add-in stays unconnected, so it seems YOU CAN'T RELOAD you own add-In.

Sorry, Jörg