# how to auto-unload a custom add-in in PowerPoint using C# VSTO?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint-2010

I have created an add-in in PowerPoint 2010. I need to check the current version of the PowerPoint being used by the user and if the current version is less than 14.0, I need to show a message and also that the add-in is unloaded automatically(or the user is not able to install or select the add-in).

Is there an easy way to do this? I am using C#.
Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469945/how-to-load-unload-word-add-in-programatically/18470779#18470779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [COMAddIns.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.comaddins.item%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [COMAddIn.Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.comaddin.connect%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```
COMAddIn addin = Application.COMAddIns.Item("yourAddinProgId");
addin.Connect = false;
```

This will cause the `Shutdown` event of your Add-In to be raised. But you'll have to do all the cleanup yourself (undo everything you did on startup).

Comment: Thanks Cremor,
I had done it using COMAddIns.Item and had Passed 1(trial and error) as the input parameter and it worked. 
But I am still not convinced about the AddInProgId. How do I get to know this value?

Comment: @gopal Iterate over `Application.COMAddIns` and look at the `ProgId` property of each `COMAddIn` object. Should be quite clear what yours is once you know them all.